# Enabling dhcp snooping on Cisco 3750 running DHCP server?

Tags: cisco, dhcp

I have been considering enabling the `ip dhcp snooping` option to avoid potential issues with users attaching wireless access points and the like.

All of the examples I've seen show using a trusted VLAN that has the DHCP server running on it... In the case I'm working with the DHCP server is running on the 3750 itself. Even the [official documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750e_3560e/software/release/15-0_1_se/configuration/guide/scg3750e/swdhcp82.html) appears this way.

What if any special steps do I need to take, considering that the the switch is also acting as the DHCP server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the switch is providing DHCP services, then the only difference should be that you should not need to "trust" any port.

The reason why is that the trusted ports are allowed to receive (and not drop) DHCP server types of messages (ACK, NAK, OFFER, etc).  Since the switch is generating them, it won't be receiving them on any port.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if there was some internal loopback type port that I'd need to include.